# Multiple circles with shading in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the shapes given below using tikz.
[image]

Problem is, I am not quite familier with tikz. The piece of code, so far I wrote is given below

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,0) circle (1.0); \draw [-stealth](1.5,0) -- (6.0,0);
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](8,0) circle (1.0); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone please help with the diagram I am looking for? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not quite know what your problem is with the code? Please clarify. Do you mean something like this:

Outer ring is **shaded** with `\shadedraw`:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,0) circle (1.0) node [black,yshift=-1.5cm] {Some Text}; 
    \draw [-stealth](1.5,0) -- (6.0,0) node[midway,above] {U};
    \shadedraw[shading=radial,outer color=red!60,inner color=white,draw=none](8,0) circle (1.0);
    \filldraw[draw=none, fill=red!5,](8,0) circle (0.8) node [black,yshift=-1.5cm] {Outer ring is shaded};
    
     \shadedraw[shading=radial,outer color=red!60,inner color=white,draw=none](7,4) circle (0.8);
    \filldraw[draw=none, fill=red!5,](6.9,3.9) circle (0.6) node [black,yshift=-1.2cm] {$e^{-}=|a,b\rangle$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Roland. Thank you for your help. Can I add a level $e^{-}=|a,b\rangle$ at the center of the circle on the top right?

Comment: @ felix I do not know what you mean with level. Do you mean label then yes (see edit).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[red!60, fill=red!5, very thick] (-1,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw [-Stealth](1.5,0) -- node[above]{U} (6.0,0);
\filldraw[red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, even odd rule] (8,0) circle[radius=1.5] circle[radius=1];
\filldraw[red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, even odd rule] (9,3) circle[radius=0.8] (8.9,2.9) circle[radius=0.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled circles]

Comment: @ hpekristiansen, Thank you!